# am335x ti-linux 4.9.80 ubi NAND flash rootfs partition not recognized

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a strange problem with ubi partition recognition by ti-linux kernel 4.9.80. On the kernel ti-4.9.24 everything works fine, kernel discovers partitions and create. On 4.9.80 I have a log as following

```
[    1.664947] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added
[    1.678146] omap-gpmc 50000000.gpmc: GPMC revision 6.0
[    1.683470] gpmc_mem_init: disabling cs 0 mapped at 0x0-0x1000000
[    1.691850] nand: device found, Manufacturer ID: 0xXX, Chip ID: 0xXX
[    1.698396] nand: Manufacturer XXYYZZ
[    1.702342] nand: 128 MiB, SLC, erase size: 128 KiB, page size: 2048, OOB size: 64
[    1.710051] nand: using OMAP_ECC_BCH8_CODE_HW ECC scheme
[    2.214870] UBI error: cannot open mtd NAND.file-sys, error -2[    2.220693]
```

No modification was made in U-Boot. I don't change anything in kernel defconfig. What can be wrong, why in older kernel revision it works?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: show kernel cmdline please for both kernel's

Comment: also bootlogs would be nice for both kernel version's

Comment: Hi Maquefel, sorry for delayed info on my site. The problem is in kernel dts.The Kernel 4.9.24 takes partition information from U-Boot. The Kernel 4.9.80 don't get any information about partition from U-Boot. I resolved the problem by adding partition information in NAND section in DTS. This resolved problem.